# Glob ignore node test files

Tags: glob

my project structure is similar with this:

```
dist
  - *
node_modules
  - *
source
  - *.js
  - *.spec.js
  - *.test.js
  - *.vue
  - __tests__
tests
  - *.js
  - *.spec.js
  - *.test.js
```

I try create a glob for get only code files `vue` and `js`, but I unknown like retire `spec` and `test` files in `source` directory.

My current glob is: `project/!(node_modules|dist|__tests__|tests)**/*.+(!(spec|test)|vue|js)`

This get all files inside `source` this, ignoring `__tests__` folder. How I can ignore `*.spec.js` and `*.test.js` files too?

Answer (score 1):

This is a late answer, but maybe someone will profit from it:

`project/!(node_modules|dist|__tests__|tests)**/(!(*.spec|*.test)|.vue|.js)`

The magical part is this one: `/**/!(*.test).js`, where you ignore all files containing `.test.js` and importing all other .js files.

Comment: You might have to add an extra globstar after your `!(pattern|pattern)**` if you want to match any content in sub directories. Something llike `/path/!(pattern|pattern)**/**/*.{spec, text, vue, js}`